# Why won't my code populate a row in the mysql table?

Tags: php

I am trying to allow for user registration, and the code comes back without any errors, but nothing shows up in my db. I can't for the life of me find out why. I don't see anything wrong, but maybe one of you can help me?

Here's the full php file:

```
<?php

require "includes/constants.php";

$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $uLength = strlen($username);
}

if ($uLength >= 4 && $uLength <= 15)
{
}
else
{
    die("Your username must be between 4 and 15 characters.");
}

if($username == "")
{
    die("You didn't tell me what to call you! Please enter a username.");
}

if(isset($_POST['pwd'])) {
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
    $pLength = strlen($pwd);
}

if ($pLength >= 6 && $pLength <= 41)
{
}
else
{
    die("Password must be between 6 and 41 characters.");
}

if($pwd == "")
{
    die("Please enter a password and verify it.");
}

if(isset($_POST['pwd_conf'])) {
    $pwd_conf = $_POST['pwd_conf'];
}
if($pwd != $pwd_conf)
{
    die("Ouch! Your passwords don't match! Try again.");
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email1 = "@";
    $email_check = strpos($email,$email1);
}

$user_check = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,$user_check)) {
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0){
        die("Username is already in use!<br>");
    }
}

$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$pwd', '$email')";

if(!$query)
{
    die("Unfortunately, we can't sign you up because we have problems: ".mysql_error());
}
else
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: You have not queried the database, you've only populated the `$query` variable with your INSERT statement. You need to execute that query, still.

Comment: I assume you don't get any errors printed when you run the code? Edit: @SetSailMedia Hit the nail on the head.

Comment: You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples to get you started.

Comment: SetSailMedia seems to be right. @query is only a string holding the query. It must be executed as well.

Comment: @AndyLester Thank you. I appreciate your input on that.

Comment: You're using `mysql_error()`, which is obsolete and incompatible with the `mysqli` functions you're using elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You build a query string, but then never never execute it...

```
1. $sql = "INSERT ..."
2. ???
3. come to SO to ask why
```

Also note that you're mixing mysqli and mysql calls (mysql_error call in particular after you define the INSERT query.. The two libraries are NOT interchangeable and NOT compatible with each other

Also note that while you ARE using prepared statements (yay!) you're using them utterly incorrectly (boo hiss) and are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score -1):

You need to use mysql_query() function before if(!$query)
Something else

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(!$result){
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting using the obsolete `mysql_query()` function instead of the better `mysqli` API that the OP is already using.